# Java and Xml basics and learning

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Where can I find good introduction of Java and XML binding stuff? please post only the resources you know and thought would help a begineer

Comment: Did you try it with google? http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/ Btw: It's unclear what you mean: JAXB, simple XML (SAX, DOM), WSDL and SOAP, JAX-WS, JAX-RS, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaXML/article.html) for a general xml overview in java in [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html) in particular to getting started with JAXB.

Answer (score 1):

JAXB is a good place to venture if you are into it.
[The Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazf.html) is sufficient for most intro. stuffs.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The [**EclipseLink Wiki**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink) contains many JAXB (JSR-222) examples.  The following one is aimed at beginners:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

I also have a very active [**Java XML & JSON Binding**](http://blog.bdoughan.com/) blog that covers many JAXB concepts.  Some posts you may find helpful as a beginner include:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

If you mean XML binding in terms of JAX-WS (SOAP) or JAX-RS (RESTful) Web Services, you may find the following links useful:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html  - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html